# Finding subsets of all the 3-dimensional vectors over finite field, such that every triple is independent

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have a set of points $P = \{(x_i, y_i) : 0 < i < k\}$ in the general position on the plane (no three collinear), then the matrix constructed by having the $i$th row ($R_i$) equal to $(x_i, y_i, 1)$ will have the property that every three rows are linearly independent.

I am a bit rusty on my linear algebra but I expect this is the case because if you have $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, and $c_1 R_1 + c_2 R_2 = R_3$ then by examining the third coordinate you can conclude that the third point is an affine combination of the the first two, violating the assumption of no three collinear.

You can make $P$ as large as you want (perturbing the points in it to achieve general position). I want to understand what can be said about the bounds on the size of $P$ when a finite field $F$ is used instead of $\mathbb{R}$. Is there a concise formula for this?

More generally, I am curious what happens when you ease the restriction on the third coordinate:

- $S$ is a subset of vector space $F^3$.
- All sets of three distinct vectors from $S$, that is the members of $\binom{S}{3}$, are linearly independent.
- How large can $S$ be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question (where the 3rd entry is fixed to be $1$ in every vector), the vectors $(1,a,a^2)$ are linearly independent for any 3 distinct choices of $a$ in the field (due to the Vandermonde determinant formula, you can look it up). Thus the maximal size set you can come up with when the 3rd coordinate is $1$ for every vector in the set is at least size $|F|$.

The more general question (not fixing the 3rd coordinate) seems much harder.